# Discerning whether a value of 255 is genuine data or an error output

Tags: c, matlab

I'm using a microcontroller to send unsigned 8-bit data to Matlab. Whenever there is any data loss, Matlab displays a value of 255. The underlying code of the Matlab program that interfaces with the WIN32 USB APIs shows that a value of -1 is returned for a range of errors. Since the data is of the unsigned 8-bit type, a value of -1 would be interpreted as 255, which explains why the latter number is displayed when a transmission error has occurred.

So, how could one tell whether a value of 255 represents genuine data or an error output?

Thanks and cheers!

Comment: This isn't clear.  If your data is being transmitted as unsigned, then where does -1 come from?

Comment: I had a closer look at the types of errors that returned a value of -1, e.g. connection failure. But I couldn't find (to my best ability) any specific line of code in the USB interface files that returns a value of -1 if the serial data isn't received successfully.

In my case, a sequence of values of 255 very likely indicate transmission errors because the status flag counters on the microcontroller reveal that data has been dropped during that time.

So, I wonder whether Matlab returns -1 by default for this sort of situation. If so, my original problem remains.

Answer (score 2):

(This is only a partial answer.)

This sounds similar to the way C's standard character input is done.

The `fgetc()` function returns an `int` result, which is either the value `EOF` (typically `-1`), if there was an error or there's no more data to read, or the value of the character that was successfully read, treated as an `unsigned char` and converted to `int`.

If you store the value returned by `fgetc()` in a signed `char` object (note that plain `char` may be either signed or unsigned), a value of `-1` could indicate *either* that `fgetc()` returned `EOF`, *or* that it successfully read a byte with the value `0xFF`.  That's the problem with this kind of in-band signalling; it can be difficult to distinguish between an error indication and valid data that happens to look like an error indication.

With `fgetc()`, there are two ways to resolve this.  You can store the result in an `int`, which means you'll get distinct values for `EOF` (-1) and for `0xFF` (255).  Or you can call the `feof()` and `ferror()` functions after calling `fgetc()`; if either returns a true value, you know that the `EOF` indicated an actual error or end-of-file condition.

You haven't told us enough about the interface between your microcontroller and Matlab to know how you can make this distinction.  If there's some other function you can call, something similar to `feof()` or `ferror()`, you could call it when you get a -1 or 255 result to determine what that result means.  Or, if possible, you might consider modifying the interface you're using so it returns a result bigger than one byte, so that the error indication `-1` is distinct from all possible valid data values.

Comment: The program that I'm using is actually an example (that came with an open-source library) whose code I've slightly edited in order to vary the number of bytes received. Through several functions spread over a few files, the program indirectly calls an executable file that interfaces with the USB port.

As I mentioned in a reply to Oli Charlesworth above, I couldn't find any specific line of code in the USB interface files that returns a value of -1 if some serial data doesn't get through. Hence, I wonder whether Matlab returns -1 by default in this sort of situation and what I should do if so.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the function is supposed to return -1 upon failure, there is no way that reasonable output would return 255. If the function can return -1, it's using a signed 8-bit return, not an unsigned which means its return range should be -128 -> 128. 255 would never be genuine data.

Comment: Please read my reply to Keith Thompson above. The main program that receives and displays the data specifies the use of unsigned 8-bit data, which is the same type sent by the microcontroller. So, either there's a mistake in one of the linked functions, or Matlab returns a value of -1 by default when it encounters this sort of data error. I'm still trying to follow the code in all the linked files to determine whether the problem is with the former. But if it's the latter case, wouldn't a default value of -1 be returned as 255 in an unsigned situation? I haven't found any information on this.